Android Studio, Google TV, cannot click Apps on home screen
I'm new to Android Studio.
I created a new device, google tv, 4k
After creation, I can click Settings on the home screen, and everything works.
But the Apps and Library buttons on the home screen, when clicked, do nothing.
I want to install an app from the Google Play store...
google tv home screen 
Can someone assist? thx
Click Apps and go to the google play store

The Android Emulator from Android Studio is just that an emulator for developing your own apps. Any Google Play Store app that comes with the emulator is a facsimile and you should not expect to be able to download/install production apps through that version of the Play Store.

Clear. Thanks for your answer. Is there any tool you can recommend for Windows, where I can install our app from the Store and take video recordings and screenshots for documentation purposes?

Odd that you are developing without a Google TV device like Chromecast with Google TV which runs Android and can be used with adb over WiFi and regular Android device screen capture tools like scrcpy subject to app specific DRM/security settings.

But I'm not developing. I just want to find the easiest way to run an existing Android App from a remote-connected-device, or emulated on my computer, so that I can do screenrecording for documentation. This without having to run the source code. Is there an easier option then?

StackOverflow is for programming topics only. You can search for Android game emulators which might satisfy your issue (recommendations off-topic here), ask on Software Recommendations with specific details of what you are trying to achive, or if you have a physical device you may be able to record directly on device or with a PC
